Tariffs, Interest Rates and Inflation
It seems  to me that if the US put on broad based high tariffs that would slow down the economy. As a result, there  would be less borrowing and lower long term interest rates. It also seems to me that there would be a one bump up in the price level but high and steady tariffs would not be inflationary in the long run. That is, there a one time increase in inflation and then it would go back down.
I have been told that tariffs lead to higher interest rates. I do not understand why. What am I missing?
